# How to findViewById in a Fragment from another layout, not the one inflated as the root layout?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview

I am using a Fragment with a ViewPager, I need to set text in the ViewPager from my fragment but I am unable to, as I a keep getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

This is how I have initialized the TextViews from the ViewPager's XML file:

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container, false);
.
.
contentHeading = root.findViewById(R.id.content_heading);
contentBody = root.findViewById(R.id.content_body);
.
. 
return root;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to directly access from child layout.
A simple way is  using interfaces.
You can define an interface in Fragment constructor  then implement it in root Fragment which hosts viewPager .

```
interface SomeInterface
{
public void callback (Type xxx)
}
```

Parent fragment must implement interface to listen any callBack

```
 ParentFragment implements SomeInterface
    {
    ...
         @override
         public void callBack(Type xxx)
         {
                //Change view pager 
         }
    }
```

and then pass this fragment as a listener in your viewpager constructor and childFragment constructor.

Comment: I am still new to Android studio, so can you please help me out? Do I have to create another fragment for this? How do I setup a listener with this fragment? The whole process is still not clear to me.

Comment: i found another answer  here .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500413/change-viewpager-fragment-from-child-fragment

Comment: Actually I want to change my viewpager from the parent fragment that contains the viewpager

Comment: Not the other way round

Comment: where did you use findviewByid ?. it must be placed in onViewCreated()

Comment: I used it inside onCreateView(), all my other findViewByIds are working find, just the ones that are in a different layout than the inflated root layout.